# Finalizar contador simultáneamente

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Como lograr que el siguiente contador cuando llegue al final, finalice simultáneamente en todos los países y no por zona horaria, es decir si necesito que el contador finalice a las 12pm en Bogotá, finalice a las 3am en Sydney y no a las 12pm

```
$(function (){
var x = 0;
function countdown() {

    var now = new Date();
    var currentTime = now.getTime();

    var eventDate = [
        //el evento inicia en
        new Date('Sep 10, 2018 00:00:00'),
    ];

    if(eventDate[x].getTime() <= currentTime){
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Evento iniciado";
    } else{
        var remTime = eventDate[x].getTime() - currentTime;

        var sec = Math.floor(remTime / 1000);
        var min = Math.floor(sec / 60);
        var hur = Math.floor(min / 60);
        var day = Math.floor(hur / 24);

        hur %= 24;
        min %= 60;
        sec %= 60;

        hur = (hur < 10) ? "0" + hur : hur;
        min = (min < 10) ? "0" + min : min;
        sec = (sec < 10) ? "0" + sec : sec;

        $('.seconds').text(sec);
        $('.minutes').text(min);
        $('.hours').text(hur);
        $('.days').text(day);


        setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
    }
}

countdown();});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asígnale una fecha absoluta a la hora del evento.

Si yo pongo `new Date('Sep 10, 2018 00:00:00')` esa fecha son las 00:00:00 del 10 de Septiembre según **mi zona horaria**. Si alguien abre el browser desde Sidney, será esa fecha según **su zona horaria**.

```js
console.log(new Date('Sep 10, 2018 00:00:00').toGMTString())
```

Me imprime: `Mon, 10 Sep 2018 03:00:00 GMT`. Nótese: **03:00:00 GMT** significa que cuando en Chile (donde yo estoy) son las 00:00:00, en Greenwich son las 3AM del día siguiente.

Si en cambio pasas el valor como una fecha en estándar ISO:

```js
console.log(new Date('2018-09-10T00:00:00Z').toGMTString());
```

Te devolverá `Mon, 10 Sep 2018 00:00:00 GMT`, el momento en que en el meridiano de Greenwich (GMT 0) sean las  00:00:00 del 10 de Septiembre.

Te toca a ti hacer el cálculo de cuántas horas restarle para que ese parámetro ISO sea el momento que quieres en Bogotá, supongo que restándole 3 o 4 horas.

Si Bogotá está en esta época en GMT-4, entonces tu evento debiera fijarse como `new Date('2018-09-09T20:00:00Z')`

Comment: Funciona perfecto, muchas gracias